# Stack not finding C library in non-standard location

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am creating bindings to some C libraries, but I am unable to get Stack to find them.

My stack.yaml file has these declarations:

```
extra-include-dirs: 
- c:\inc
extra-lib-dirs: 
- c:\lib
```

My cabal file has these declarations:

```
library
  ...
  extra-libraries:     fmod, fsbank
  include-dirs:        c:\inc
  includes:            fmod.h, fsbank.h
  extra-lib-dirs:      c:\lib
```

`fmod.DLL` and `fsbank.DLL` are located in `c:\lib`. `fmod.h` and `fsbank.h` are located in `c:\inc`.

When I build I get an error message: `Missing C Libraries: fmod, fsbank`

How can I point Stack to these files?

I'm pretty sure the header files are being located, because when I comment out `extra-include-dirs` and `include-dirs`, the error message also states 
`Missing (or bad header) file: fmod.h`

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and Stack 1.4.0.

Comment: Could it be a forward backward slash issue?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I tried building with all forward slashes and all back slashes in the yaml and cabal files and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing

```
extra-libraries:     fmod, fsbank
```

To

```
extra-libraries:     fmod64, fsbank64
```